# What is the Republic City Police Force (metalbender cops) insignia?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

What is the insignia worn by the metalbending cops?  The one that looks like a gold geometric ant's head (with mandibles):

[image: Chief Bei Fong's get-up]

Is it a spin on something from the previous series?

Answer (score 5):

**As far as I can tell it is just an icon for Republic City's Police Force.** It is the cultural equivalent of a sheriff's or marshal's star. Only the police are seen wearing it.

There are no easily recognized previous references for the icon in the series. Nor does it have any recognizable relationship to any particular Chinese characters. It is notable because the series has made an effort to keep such symbols to a minimum.

That said, using an ant as a representation of the earth is not an unusual idea. Ants live in the earth, use the earth to build, are industrious and hardworking and for a police force, it might make sense to consider the ant for its success in defending the colony against invaders, their armored carapace and the service to the community. The sign of a good icon is its ability to be recognized and its message remembered.

Answer (score -2):

If you look closely you see the shape resembles Toph's hair!

That's all it is.